# Increase index of split in Python

Tags: python, indexing, split

Well, I have a problem in a Python script, I need to do is that the index of the split function, increases automatically with every iteration of the loop. I do this:

```
tag = "\'"
while loop<=302:
        for line in f1.readlines():
            if tag in line:
                word = line.split(tag)[num] #num is the index I need to increase

        text = "Word: "+word+"."

        f.write(text)

        num = num + 1
        loop = loop + 1
```

But...the "num" variable on index doesn't change...it simply stays the same. The num index indicates the word I need to take. So this is why "num = num + 1" would have to increase...

What is the problem in the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding.  Could you put a short (2-3 line) example input file and then an expected output for that file?

Comment: The input file, is a plain text with words between simple quotes, separates with commas. The output file, is an other plain text that contains word: first word of split, Word: Second word of split, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. But I think you want to move `num = num + 1` into the for loop and if statement.

```
tag = "\'"
while loop<=302:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        if tag in line:
            word = line.split(tag)[num] #num is the index I need to increase
            num = num + 1

    text = "Word: "+word+"."

    f.write(text)
    loop = loop + 1
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Yes, I think this seems like what s/he wants.

Comment: I bet it something like this, but it's possible that the increasement should be outside the if-statement. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks everybody, the problem was because num = num + 1, was outside of if.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Benyi's comment in the question - do you just want this for the individual sentences? You might not need to index.

```
>>> mystring = 'hello i am a string'
>>> for word in mystring.split():
         print 'Word: ',word


Word:  hello
Word:  i
Word:  am
Word:  a
Word:  string
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of things wrong with this.
First

```
while loop <= 302:
   for line in f1.readlines():
```

f1.readlines() is going be [] for every iteration past the first

Second

```
for line in f1.readline():
   word = line.split(tag)[num]
   ...
text = "Word: "+word+"."
```

Even if you made the for loop work, `text` will always be using the last iteration of the `word`. Maybe this is desired behavior, but it seems strange.

Third

```
while loop<=302:
    ...
    loop = loop += 1
```

Seems like it would be better written as

```
for _ in xrange(302):
```

Since loop isn't used at all inside that scope. This is assuming loop starts at 0, if it doesn't then you just adjust 302 to however many iterations you wanted.

Lastly

```
num = num + 1
```

This is outside your inner loop, so num will always be the same for the first iteration, then won't matter latter because of the empty `f1.readlines()` as stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach to your problem as mentioned by you in the comment. Consider input.txt has the following entry:

```
this is a an input file.
```

then the Following code will give you the desired output

```
lines = []
with open (r'C:\temp\input.txt' , 'r') as fh:
    lines = fh.read()

with open (r'C:\temp\outputfile.txt' , 'w') as fh1:
    for words in lines.split():
        fh1.write("Words:"+ words+ "\n" )
```